# Can I listen to control tower frequencies on a ham radio legally

Tags: air-traffic-control, usa, radio

Is there a frequency I can tune into to listen to airport I’m in Durham by RDU AIRPORT and would like to listen in on a ham radio only legally

Comment: Are you asking about USA rules?

Comment: Aviation communications frequencies are typically 118.0 to 137.0 MHz. If your radio can receive those frequencies, I see no reason why you can’t listen.

Answer (score 9):

In North America, just buy an air-band radio and listen to Raleigh-Durham tower all you like, or if your ham unit receives the aviation VHF frequencies, do that.  Or find it on [LiveATC.net](https://www.liveatc.net/search/?icao=rdu)  It's only illegal to broadcast without authorization, not listen in.

Comment: A list of RDU frequencies is [here](https://skyvector.com/airport/RDU/Raleigh-Durham-International-Airport).

Comment: Note that many ham radios are capable of receiving those frequencies but don't have an AM demodulator, only FM or SSB.

Comment: Also, while it doesn't apply to the OP in the US, for completeness it should be noted there are some countries (e.g. UK) where even listening to a radio broadcast is illegal if you aren't the intended recipient.

Comment: @StephenS Same for Germany: it's illegal to listen to ATC radio as long as you are not involved somehow. If you wander around in typical planespotter areas and wear earplugs, chances are that you are being asked what you listen to.

Comment: Thanks. Added North America reference.